# Do Postgres multicolumn indexes get used for OR queries?

Tags: postgresql

This seems like a straightforward question, but I can't find the answer online.

I'm using Postgres 9.4 and have this table:

```
                                                 Table "public.title"
             Column              |          Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
---------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id                              | integer                 |           | not null | nextval('title_id_seq'::regclass) 
 name1                           | character varying(1000) |           |          | 
 name2                           | character varying(1000) |           |          | 
 name3                           | character varying(1000) |           |          | 
 name4                           | character varying(1000) |           |          |
```

And I have a multicolumn index:

```
"idx_title_names" btree (name1, name2, name3, name4)
```

But for OR queries, the index isn't being used:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "title" WHERE ("title"."name1" = 'foo'
   OR "title"."name3" = 'foo' OR "title"."name3" = 'foo' OR "title"."name4" = 'foo');

 Gather  (cost=1000.00..436451.46 rows=659 width=4500) (actual time=561.418..1297.877 rows=3222 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title  (cost=0.00..435385.56 rows=275 width=4500) (actual time=551.627..1286.724 rows=1074 loops=3)
         Filter: (((name1)::text = 'foo'::text) OR ((name2)::text = 'foo'::text) OR ((name3)::text = 'foo'::text) OR ((name4)::text = 'foo'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1231911
 Planning Time: 0.102 ms
 Execution Time: 1298.148 ms
```

Is this because these indexes don't work with OR queries?

And: if so, is my best bet just to create 4 separate standard indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` [is often a performance problem](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/) in SQL.

This index cannot be used for a condition like that.

Your best bet is to create four single-column indexes and hope for a *Bitmap Or*:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.title (name1);
CREATE INDEX ON public.title (name2);
CREATE INDEX ON public.title (name3);
CREATE INDEX ON public.title (name4);
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a GIN index on the array of the columns, then use an array operator:

```
create index on title using gin (array[name1,name2,name3,name4]);
```

Then use

```
SELECT * 
FROM title 
WHERE array[name1,name2,name3,name4] @> array['foo'];
```

Note that a GIN index is a bit more expensive to maintain than a BTree index.

Answer (score 1):

Having index on `(col1, col2, col3, etc)` it will be used for conditions/ordering on `col1`, or `col1` and `col2`, or `col1`, `col2` and `col3` etc. It will be not used for conditions/ordering only on `col3` for example.

Look at this:

```
# create table t as select random() as a, random() as b from generate_series(1,1000000);
# create index i on t(a,b);
# analyze t;
# explain analyze select * from t where a > 0.9;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=2246.83..8863.15 rows=96826 width=16) (actual time=10.973..28.023 rows=99311 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (a > '0.9'::double precision)
   Heap Blocks: exact=5406
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i  (cost=0.00..2222.62 rows=96826 width=0) (actual time=10.251..10.252 rows=99311 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (a > '0.9'::double precision)
 Planning Time: 0.348 ms
 Execution Time: 31.054 ms

 # explain analyze select * from t where b > 0.9;
                                                QUERY PLAN                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..17906.00 rows=99117 width=16) (actual time=0.015..70.505 rows=100137 loops=1)
   Filter: (b > '0.9'::double precision)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 899863
 Planning Time: 0.090 ms
 Execution Time: 73.656 ms
```

However when you are using `or` condition the DBMS actually should to perform several queries, for our example `select * from t where a > 0.9 or b > 0.9` is equal to `select * from t where a > 0.9` (index could be used) and `select * from t where b > 0.9` (index could not be used) thus instead of two actions (scan index then scan whole table) DBMS performs only one action (scan whole table)

Hope it explains why your index is not used for your query.